# How to tell when number of process page faults will affect performance?

Tags: performance, performancecounter, page-fault

There is a Windows performance counter for the number of page faults a process generates.  Is there a rule-of-thumb threshold at which performance will be affected?

Comment: Better off asking this on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is always affected with page faults - the memory access is much, much slower.

Once your entire machine starts hitting around 100 page faults/s, you're very close to saturating the random access performance of your swap file